# Indenting the Second line of Label to be exactly below the first line through CSS

Tags: html, css, text-indent

I am hoping to indent the second line of the label so that it never goes behind the starting point of first line.

Here is my HTML:-

```
        <label for="ui-multiselect-edit-1" title="" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-hover">
    <input id="ui-multiselect-edit-1" name="multiselect_edit-selective" type="checkbox"   value="Cost-of something" title="">

    <span>Cost-driven / restructuring transformations</span>
</label>
```

### This is how it looks

[image]

Can I tweak it so that transformations don't go behind the Cost?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to float the `input` element to the left and then change the display of the `span` element to `table`. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/nwT68/)

```
label > input {
    float:left;
}
label > span {
    display:table;
}
```

It's worth noting that [IE7 doesn't support](http://caniuse.com/css-table) `display:table`.

---

Alternatively, change the display of the `span` element to `block` and add a `margin-left` value equal to the width of the checkbox element + padding.. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/y7ZPV/)

```
label > span {
    margin-left:28px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you have to change it to `display:table` do you?  Can't you just float them both left, and change the `span` to a `div`?  Similar to your `alternative` approach, but I see no reason to make it a span at that point :P

Comment: @nzifnab Yea, something like that would work, however you would need to set a height on the `input` element.. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/b5gdB/) .. sure, this works, but I assumed that the amount of text would be variable. The `display:table` method should work well with dynamic content of varying characters/lengths

Answer (score 1):

And one more approach:

```
label[for] {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

label[for] input{
    vertical-align: top;
}

label[for] span
{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
}
```